# Compare with and compare to

Tags: comparisons

I often get confused by the advice about compare to and compare with...especially as I find many native speakers using them differently...

Is there any conclusive advice on this matter please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Compared with" vs "Compared to"—which is used when?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583/compared-with-vs-compared-to-which-is-used-when)

Comment: At the duplicate, Sven Yargs' answer gives more accurate guidance. As English is usage-driven rather than imposed from above by a Grammar Czar, and you rightly observe that 'many native speakers us[e] them differently', the answer _must_ be that the only conclusive advice is that there is no absolute rule.